# How to repair Simulink SLX file?

Tags: matlab, simulink, corruption

One of my Simulink SLX files has stopped opening as a model. Apparently it was corrupted. Are there any means to repair such a files or extract some information of them? File looks like being a MZ executable. Where is the block schema stored?

Answer (score 2):

SLX is a compressed file which contains XML files with model information. You can try opening the SLX file in winzip and check. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/saving-a-model.html#btbr7kx-1 for SLX format. I do not think there is any utility to repair corrupted SLX files.

Answer (score 1):

[DiffPlug's Simulink Viewer](http://www.diffplug.com/features/simulink) has an .slx parser that was developed independent of The Mathworks, and it's a little more "lenient" than The Mathworks' implementation.  You might want to try opening your model in DiffPlug's viewer (it's free, so you don't have much to lose I guess...).

That way you'll at least be able to scout around the model so you can see what piece has been corrupted.

Disclaimer: I work for DiffPlug.

If there's a lot of time invested in the model, I'd be happy to open your model up and poke around inside it using our internal API.  It'd only take me a few minutes, and it might be an easy fix like a mis-matched Stateflow id.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extension 'original' from the file name 'X.slx.original'. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually still load the system using `load_system()`, use `bdroot` to see if it loaded, then use `save_system()` to save what is returned by `bdroot`, using a new filename.  The new model should open correctly.